# How do we use CimCmdlets in Powershell Core on Linux Environment?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-core, cim

I'm trying to execute the CimCmdlets on Linux Powershell but it seems like this module is only available for windows. Is there any workaround to run these commands from cmdlets module on Linux?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/?view=powershell-7.2

When I run command following command I get,

```
Get-CimInstance
```

> Get-CimInstance: The term 'Get-CimInstance' is not recognized as a name of
> a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the
> spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
> is correct and try again.

or if there's any workaround for this, that would work too

Comment: They are part of PowerShells deployment as of v3. Would be helpful if you could show us how you're running the commands, and if you're getting any error.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala edited the question. FYI I'm able to run these commands on windows but on Linux seems like the module isn't there.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala any update?

Comment: I think some form of wmi comes with dsc for linux?  (OMI)  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/getting-started/lnxgettingstarted?view=dsc-1.1#installing-omi

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it looks like MS aren't bringin the CIMCmdlets to anything bar windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/?view=powershell-7.3